How to pass header to authentication in httpstarget method while using PACT?
While creating pact verification test I am using HttpsTestTarget method. But the problem is my service need send autentication token in the call. How can we run this? please advise.
Details: The project using Java, Pact and Quarkus extentions (io.quarkiverse.pact:quarkus-pact-provider and io.quarkiverse.pact:quarkus-pact-consumer).
Below is my cURL:
curl --location 'https://gateway.production.xpto.io/xpto/v2/xpto?attribute=%23xpto_client' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 3rdcD=V8KoW!eJaPjWx04lhuVUqXFyr2Bz-HjANr7Fy9eUzOW!7JJXeVwPe6NTSAlPxxn4C!qXzsqz!UzSrj/gH2o-BL=S?IsbMrb/zG00pjOWm7U=08PYz5UPko1JttfuI!v6rRH4P8fsJ-M6E0kR0Ds7tsqbRbjGGt8NsdzO4VPG1/U3uIYZ7IG/yWG8-1tUyq8V4DPmwtmxM/5CieFaPHhUJyRyjR!24K-7m4FGNd??gCr!t57JTvW2vrjEpj'

Below is my verification test:
package com.company.pact.provider;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestTemplate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.HttpsTestTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationContext;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.State;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.loader.PactBroker;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
@Provider("XPTOProvider")
@PactBroker(host = "localhost", port = "9292")
public class XPTOProviderContractTest {

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.setTarget(new HttpsTestTarget("gateway.production.xpto.io", 443, "/xpto/v2/xpto?attribute=%23xpto_client"));
    }

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }

    @State("test GET")
    public void testGet() {
        System.out.println("test GET");
        
    }

}


We managed to resolve the issue by referring to the documentation available at this link.
To solve the problem, we needed to modify the pactVerificationTestTemplate as follows:
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpRequest;

@TestTemplate
@ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) throws Exception {
    request.addHeader("Authorization", getAccessToken());
    context.verifyInteraction();
}

Additionally, don't forget to add the import statement:
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpRequest;

This modification allows us to adjust the requests before they are sent, which was crucial in resolving our issue.
